# VBA macro -- hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create a VBA macro which would allow me to edit all selected hyperlinks in a column and change "text to display" to the same word for all. For example, if this was the column:

```
www.google.com/search=cars
www.google.com/search=houses
www.google.com/search=cities
```

I would want to highlight those three elements of the column and change the text to display to "Google Search" so that the outcome would be this:

```
Google Search
Google Search
Google Search
```

Edit: So I found a macro similar to what I want to do on the microsoft [support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247507), but my issue is that this macro targets all the hyperlinks in the sheet while I'd want to select a specific column to edit the hyperlinks.

```
Sub HyperLinkChange()
   Dim oldtext As String
   Dim newtext As String
   Dim h As Hyperlink
```

oldtext = "http://www.microsoft.com/" 
 newtext = "http://www.msn.com/" 

   For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
   x = InStr(1, h.Address, oldtext)
   If x > 0 Then
       If h.TextToDisplay = h.Address Then
            h.TextToDisplay = newtext
       End If
       h.Address = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
       Substitute(h.Address, oldtext, newtext)
   End If
   Next End Sub

Comment: What part exactly are you having a problem with?  On this site you're expected to show what you have tried so far, not just describe what you want to do.  If you have any existing code, the please update your question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on the current selection:

```
Sub SetLinkText()

Dim LinkText As String
Dim h As Hyperlink

    LinkText = InputBox("Enter link text")

    If LinkText = "" Then Exit Sub

    For Each h In Selection.Hyperlinks
        h.TextToDisplay = LinkText
    Next

End Sub
```